# How do we prove that $L \int_a^b f= L\int_a^c f + L \int\limits_c^b f$, where $L\int_a^b f$ is the lower integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

In Spivak's *Calculus*, Chapter 14 "The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus", there is the following snippet

> If $f$ is any bounded function on $[a,b]$, then
>
> $$\sup\{L(f,P)\} \text{ and } \inf\{U(f,P)\}$$
>
> will both exist, even if $f$ is not integrable. These numbers are
> called the **lower integral** of $f$ on $[a,b]$ and the **upper
> integral** of $f$ on $[a,b]$, respectively, and will be denoted by
>
> $$L\int\limits_a^b f \text{ and } U\int\limits_a^b f$$
>
> The lower and upper integrals both have several properties which the
> integral possesses. In particular, if $a<c<b$, then
>
> $$L \int\limits_a^b f= L\int\limits_a^c f + L \int\limits_c^b f\tag{1}$$
>
> and
>
> $$U \int\limits_a^b f= U\int\limits_a^c f + U \int\limits_c^b f$$
>
> The proofs of these facts are left as an exercise, since they are
> quite similar to the corresponding proofs for integrals. The results
> for integrals are actually a corollary of the results for upper and
> lower integrals, because $f$ is integrable precisely when
>
> $$L\int\limits_a^b f = U\int\limits_a^b f$$

How do we prove $(1)$?

Here is my attempt

> Let
>
> $$P_1=\{a=t_0,t_1,...,t_{m-1},c=t_m\}$$
>
> $$P_2=\{ c=u_0, u_1,...,u_{n-1},b=u_n \}$$
>
> $$P=\{ a=t_0,t_1,...,t_{m-1}, c=t_m=u_0, u_1,...,u_{n-1},b=u_n\}$$
>
> be partitions of $[a,b]$. Then $P$ contains $P_1$ and $P_2$.
>
> Then
>
> $$L(f,P)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^m
>  m_i\Delta t_i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta u_i$$
>
> $$L\int\limits_a^b f = \sup\{L(f,P)\}= \sup\left \{
>  \sum\limits_{i=1}^m
>  m_i\Delta t_i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta u_i \right  \}$$
>
> $$=\sup\left \{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^m m_i\Delta t_i \right \}+\sup\left
>  \{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta u_i \right  \}$$
>
> $$=\sup\{ L(f,P_1)\}+\sup\{ L(f,P_2)\}$$
>
> $$L\int\limits_a^c f + L\int\limits_c^b f$$
>
> $$\blacksquare$$

Is this correct?

As an additional detail, let's see how we obtain the corresponding result for integrals?

Note that $(1)$ is true for any bounded function $f$. $f$ doesn't need to be integrable. However, if if is integrable then

$$L\int\limits_a^b f = U\int\limits_a^b f=\int\limits_a^b f$$

Then all we have to do is sub into $(1)$. That is, since

$$L \int\limits_a^b f= L\int\limits_a^c f + L \int\limits_c^b f$$

Then

$$\int\limits_a^b f= \int\limits_a^c f + \int\limits_c^b f$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correct Proof**

Using arbitrary partitions $P_1$ of $[a,c]$ and $P_2$ of $[c,b]$, we form $P = P_1 \cup P_2$ which is a partition of $[a,b]$ and we have

$$L(f,P_1) + L(f,P_2) = L(f,P) \leqslant L\int_a^b f$$

The partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ can be varied independently and it follows by taking suprema over $P_1$ and $P_2$ succesively that

$$\tag{1}L\int_a^c f + L\int_c^b f \leqslant L \int _a^b f$$

To prove the reverse inequality, note that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ that may not include the point $c$ such that

$$L\int_a^b f - \epsilon < L(f,P)$$

Adding the point $c$ to $P$ if necessary, we get the partition P' which is a refinement of $P$ and since lower sums are increasing under partition refinement it follows that

$$L\int_a^b f - \epsilon < L(f,P) \leqslant L(f,P')$$

Now $P'$ which includes $c$ is the union of partitions  $P_1'$ of $[a,c]$ and $P_2'$ of $[c,b]$. Hence,

$$L\int_a^b f - \epsilon < L(f,P') = L(f,P_1') + L(f,P_2') \leqslant L\int_a^cf + L\int_c^b f$$

Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$ it follows that

$$\tag{2} L \int_a^b f \leqslant L \int_a^c f + L \int _c^b f$$

Together (1) and (2) imply that

$$ L \int_a^b f = L \int_a^c f + L \int _c^b f$$

Comment: In your counterexample, the functions in the $\sup$ expression cannot be varied independently. In the expression $\sup\{ \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta t_i +\sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta t_i \}$ the two sums are independent from each other. How is this situation different from you taking the $\sup$ that leads to your expression $(1)$?

Comment: @evianpring:  I'll take out that counterexample for now, as I can see it is a point of confusion.  What you did in simply writing $\sup L(P,f) = \sup L(P_1,f) + \sup L(P_2,g)$ is not valid.  How are the suprema taken?  The equality $L(P,f) = L(P_1,f) + L(P_2,f)$ is only true for a subset of partitions $\{P\}$ where $P = P_1 \cup P_2$, i.e., $P$ includes the point $c$.  Clearly you cannot be taking the supremum of $L(P,f)$ over all partitions of $[a,b]$.  At a minimum you need more justification.

Comment: My argument is based simply on the fact that for arbitrary partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$, the  lower integral is an upper bound for $L(P,f) = L(P_1 \cup P_2,f) = L(P_1,f) + L(P_2,f)$, by definition of the lower integral as the supremum of lower sums over ALL partitions of $[a,b]$. Then we have $L(P_1,f) \leqslant L\int_a^b f - L(P_2,f)$. Now we take the supremum of both sides over partitions $P_1$ to get $L\int_a^c f \leqslant L\int_a^b f - L(P_2,f)$.  Now rearrange and take the supremum over all partitions $P_2$ of $[c,b]$ to get the final result.

Comment: I see your point. Here is an attempt at rectifying my original argument based on your argument. Let $P$ be any partition of $[a,b]$. Let $P'$ be the partition formed by adding the point $c$ to $P$. Then $P'$ is of the form $\{a=t_0,...t_{m-1}, c=t_m, t_{m+1},...,t_n=n\}$. Then $L \int_a^b f = \sup\{L(f,P)\geq L(f,P')=\sum_{i=1}^m m_i \Delta t_i +\sum_{i=m+1}^n m_i\Delta t_i \geq L(f,P)$.

The last inequality is due to the fact that adding a point to a partition $P$ increases the lower sum.

Now the question is, can I take the supremum over all partitions on that last inequality?

Comment: Consider $L(f,P_1)+L(f,P_2) \geq L(f,P)$, where $P_1$ is any partition of $[a,c]$ and $P_2$ is any partition of $[c,b]$. Now, $P'=P_1 \bigcup P_2=P \bigcup { c }$. When we vary $P$, we are varying $P'$. However, going through all $P$ goes through all $P_1$ and $P_2$.

If we take the supremum of both sides over all partitions $P$ we are necessarily going through all the partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$, so it would seem to be the case that $\sup\{L(f,P_1)\}+\sup\{L(f,P_2)\} \geq \sup\{L(f,P)\}$, in which case we'd have $L\int_a^b f \geq \sup\{L(f,P_1)\}+\sup\{L(f,P_2)\} \geq \sup\{L(f,P)\}$

Comment: @evianpring: Your argument leading to $L \int_a^b f = \sup\{L(f,P)\geq L(f,P')=\sum_{i=1}^m m_i \Delta t_i +\sum_{i=m+1}^n m_i\Delta t_i \geq L(f,P)$ is correct.

Comment: I don't follow your second argument where you start with $L(f,P_1)+L(f,P_2) \geq L(f,P)$. You seem to be getting hung up on dependency of partitions when taking suprema.  None of this is necessary.  Just try to follow the arguments in my answer.  In the first one I take ARBITRARY partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$. With $P = P_1 \cup P_2$ we have $P$ dependent on $P_1,P_2$ but then I only use the fact that $L(f,P) \leqslant L\int_a^b f$.  This leaves $L(P_1,f) + L(P_2,f) \leqslant L\int_a^bf$.  Since the RHS is a constant I can take suprema over the arbitrary and independent .partitions $P_1,P_2$

Comment: ... and get the result $L\int_a^cf + L\int_c^bf \leqslant L\int_a^b f$